# JPA foreign key - insert new record if necessary?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0

Is it possible to create some combination of annotations, that provide following:

- Have 2 tables (one-2-many relationship)
- Is it possible on JPA level without programming, just create object of "one" class and if there is id set that just make it reference in "many" table and in case that id is not set, create new record in "one" table and make reference to that id in "many" table

Answer (score 1):

No. You will need to create all the objects by your self.

What you can do is to use cascade to do a automatic persist if you want to.

It would be something like:

```
a.setB(b);
b.getAList().add(a);

entityManager.persist(a);
```

And in your classes you would map like:

```
public class A {
    // other methods and ID

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;
}


public class B {
    // other methods and ID

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<A> aList;
}
```